# Getting DateTime from stored procedure error

Tags: c#, sql-server, compact-framework

I am trying to pull a `DateTime` from a stored procedure on my SQL Server.

Stored procedure variable:

```
@TempDateTime DateTime = '' OUTPUT
SET @TempDateTime = GETDATE()
```

Line that errors out in my C# CF 2.0 Program

```
DateTime tempDT = Convert.ToDateTime(sqlcmd.Parameters["@TempDateTime"].Value);
```

I get the following error, and I am at a lost on what it is. Can my stored procedure be sending back a null? I execute the stored procedure and it runs fine, on another bit of code. Getting the `DateTime` and inserting it into a table, but errors when I try to retrieve the `DateTime` var.

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled
>   Message="An {0} with {1} '{2}' is not contained by this {3}."
>
> StackTrace:
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection.RangeCheck()
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection.get_Item()
>   at Missouri_Scanning_Utility.Form1.updateDatabase()
>   at Missouri_Scanning_Utility.Form1.tmrUpdateDatabase_Tick()
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Timer._WnProc()
>   at System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationThreadContext._InternalContextMessages()
>   at Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterMainLoop()
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run()
>   at Missouri_Scanning_Utility.Program.Main()

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Did you define your `@TempDateTime` parameter in your C# code as output? `Direction = ParameterDirection.Output`

Comment: @JasonFaulkner I just did that and now that line of code gets the same error as above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are defining the parameter values to your send to your call, you have to declare the `OUTPUT` parameters accordingly.

Since you do not have the relevant portions of your code posted, here is the general procedure for doing this:

```
var tempDateTimeParam = new SqlParameter("@TempDateTime", SqlDbType.DateTime)
{ 
    Direction = ParameterDirection.Output 
};

myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
myCommand.Parameters.Add(tempDateTimeParam);
// Add additional params.

// Execute stored proc.

// Read result from output param which should now have a value.
var tempDateTimeValue = (DateTime)tempDateTimeParam.Value;
```

Comment: that was it. My line looks a little different but all is well now. 

sql.cmd.Parameters.Add("@TempDateTime", SqlDbType.DateTime).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

Comment: @Lgwells1 - Glad it was something simple. Cheers.